# Looking for space spy book with female protagonist

Tags: story-identification, novel, telepathy, espionage

Here are the details I can remember:

1. Female lead is a spy/assassin, near the beginning of the book she is seducing a man to get information, but he realizes she is a spy and she ends up killing him with a knife to the heart.
2. She has a boyfriend and this becomes an issue with her sleeping with targets to get information.
3. She is raped at one point by another male spy, pretty sure he was her boss or co-ordinator, he is described as a brutish sort of man, large, hairy, uni-brow.  I want to say she was in a relationship with him at one point (prior to any events in the novel), but can't say that for sure. His name may have been Bruno, but I don't know for sure.  She ends up poking him in the eye right as he ejaculates in order to escape.
4. She decides to retire near the end, and undergoes some sort of treatment that winds up giving her telepathy as a side effect. The doctor that is checking on her knows of others that developed this due to the treatment and tries to keep the spy agency from knowing about the telepaths.
5. The boyfriend is in a martial arts class with the female protagonist.
6. The boyfriend ends up wanting to become a spy towards the end of the book.
7. There is a detailed description of her reading the boyfriend’s mind and is overwhelmed (for lack of a better word) by how beautiful he sees her.
8. Is set on a planet other than Earth, but I don't remember where.
9. I would have read it in the mid-late 1980's, so it would have to be published before that, I read it in USA, was definitely an English book.
10. It is soft sci-fi, they have spaceships, lasers, etc, but that is not the focus of the book, it is more about the spying, espionage, fighting, and the relationship.
11. Everyone is human (or enhanced, after the "procedure"), no aliens, vampires, elves, etc.
12. Another thing I remember, there was a fight/sparring sequence in the novel where one of the guys had a fart knocked out of him during the fight (funny what we remember).

Comment: Has some similarities to the [Riley Jenson](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/172764.Full_Moon_Rising?ac=1&from_search=true#) books by [Keri Arthur](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keri_Arthur#Riley_Jenson_Guardian_Series), but those don't have space travel.  (Sci fi vampires & werewolves in a special policing unit.)

Comment: My first thought up till point 3 was "Friday" RAH's last great book. That's however clearly not this one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Except* for the publication date, you're definitely describing [*The Forever Drug*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/550011.The_Forever_Drug) by Steve Perry.  Points #3, 4 and 7 - the plot points you're most specific about - are exactly from the book.

[image]

> The sequel to Spindoc takes Venture Silk to Earth 2, home world of his lover, Zia Relanj. He is pursued by Terran intelligence; she is pursued both by her own world's covert operators, who suspect her loyalty, and by a Terran agent who wishes to extract from her body the secret of the life-prolonging drug with which she is being treated. All this means that between bouts of sex, martial-arts training sessions, and target practice, Silk and his lady have a good deal of excitement guarding their backs and just barely succeeding at it

Comment: awesome, you got it, thanks so much.  Apparently I was older than I thought when I read it :)